# Background html transition doesnt work in Firefox/IE10

Tags: css, css-transitions

I´d like some help to be sure if there isn´t any solution about this:

I made a background transition which in the html element. The transition works only in the latest Chrome, Safari and Opera. It doesn´t in IE10 and FFx.
Seems it´s because the bkg is in the html element, am I right? I tried the full sintax notation, no shorthand, it doesn´t matter.
Does anyone can confirm the reason, and does anyone know if I could do something different in order to work in IE10 and FFx? Tks!!

(The bkg keeps changing with a js function changeimage)

```
html {
    background:#000000;
    background: url(img/bkg_banana.jpg) no-repeat fixed right; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease; 
    transition: background 0.5s ease;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those styles to affect both Firefox and IE, you'll need to add -moz- (for Firefox) and -ms- (for Internet Explorer).
For example,

```
html {
-moz-background-size:cover;
-ms-background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
}
```

etc...